# Show or disprove $ \sigma\left(\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}) \cap \sigma\left(\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set.

Show or disprove:

Let be $ \varnothing \neq \mathcal{E}, \mathcal{E}^{\prime} \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega) $. Then $ \sigma\left(\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}) \cap \sigma\left(\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) $.

From the feeling, I would say that this is true because if you would choose $\mathcal{E}^{\prime} = \varnothing$ or $\mathcal{E}^{\prime} = \Omega$ once, it would be fulfilled. But what about the other cases from $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$?

Do you agree with me and if so how would one prove this formally?

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \cap \sigma\left(\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right)$ is **a** sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}$ and $\sigma\left(\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right)$ is the **smallest** sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}$. Hence $ \sigma\left(\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}) \cap \sigma\left(\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) $.

Comment: If that is the answer to it than write it please as an answer.

Comment: I've written it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the intersection of sigma-algebras is a sigma-algebra, we know that $\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \cap \sigma\left(\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right)$ is **a** sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}$. On the other hand, by definition, $ \sigma\left(\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right)$ is the **smallest** sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}$. Hence $ \sigma\left(\mathcal{E} \cap \mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}) \cap \sigma\left(\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\right) $.